# function that takes directory of .txt file and returns a dictionary based on set parameters?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, directory

I want to make a function that takes the directory of a .txt file as an input and returns a dictionary based on specific parameters. If the .txt file is empty,
then the function will return nothing. When writing this function, I request that **no imports, no list comprehension, and only for/while and if statements are used**.

This is for the sake of the content I am learning right now, and I would like to be able to learn and interpret the function step-by-step.

An example of a .txt file is below. The amount of lines can vary but every line is formatted such that they appear in the order:

word + a string of 3 numbers connected by commas.

> terra,4,5,6
>
> cloud,5,6,7
>
> squall,6,0,8
>
> terra,4,5,8
>
> cloud,6,5,7

**First I would like to break down the steps of the function**

Each component of the string that is separated by a comma serves a specific purpose:

1. The last number in the string will be subtracted by the second to last number in a string to form a value in the dictionary.

for example, the last two characters of `terra,4,5,6` will be subtracted to form a value of `[1]` in the dictionary

2. The alphabetical words will form the keys of the dictionary. If there are multiple entries of the same word in a .txt file then a single key will be formed
   and it will contain all the values of the duplicate keys.

for example, `terra,4,5,6` , `terra,4,4,6` , and `terra,4,4,7` will output `('terra', 4):[1,2,3]` as a key and value respectively.

3. However, in order for a key to be marked as a duplicate, the first values of the keys must be the same. If they are not, then they will be separate values.

For example, `terra,4,5,6` and `terra,5,4,6` will appear separately from eachother in the dictionary as `('terra', 4):[1]` and `('terra', 5):[2]` respectively.

**Example input**

if we use the example .txt file mentioned above, the input should look like `create_dict("***files/example.txt")` and should ouput a dictionary
`{('terra', 4):[1,3],('cloud', 5):[1],('squall', 6):[8],('cloud', 6):[2]}`. I will add a [link to the .txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a5oqXWdOkhuuNX5jvtUK-8BeUTmZovij/view?usp=sharing) for the sake of recreating this example. *(note that *** are placeholders for the rest of the directory)*

**What I'm Trying:**

```
testfiles = (open("**files/example.txt").read()).split('\n')
int_list = []
alpha_list = []
for values in testfiles:
    ao = values.split(',') #returns only a portion of the list. why?
for values in ao:
    if values.isnumeric():
        int_list.append(values) #retrives list of ints from list
for values in ao:
    if values.isalpha():
        alpha_list.append(values) #retrieves a list of words
{((alpha_list[0]), int(int_list[0])):(int(int_list[2])-(int(int_list[1])))} #each line will always have 3 number values so I used index
```

this returns `{('squall', 6): 1}` which is mainly just a proof of concept and not a solution to the function. I wanted to see if it was possible to use the numbers and words I found in int_list and alpha_list using indexes to generate entries in the dictionary. If possible, the same could be applied to the rest of the strings in the .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is in CSV format.
You really should be using one of these

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

since "odd" characters within a comma-separated field
are non-trivial to handle.
Better to let the library worry about such details.

Using `defaultdict(list)` is the most natural way,
the most readable way, to implement your dup key requirement.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

I know, I know, "no import";
now on to a variant solution.

---

```
    d = {}
    with open('example.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            word, nums = line.split(',', maxsplit=1)
            a, b, c = map(int, nums.split(','))
            delta = c - b
            key = (word, a)
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = []
            d[key].append(delta)
    return d
```